# Managing config files and code constants in a big project

Tags: c#, configuration, refactoring, configuration-files, code-cleanup

I'm working on a huge C# codebase (~300 KLOC). The components of the system use config files scattered across the folder hierarchy. Values that are read from config in one place are stored in a constant in another. There are several copies of the same config in different folders, copied and checked in once, and then never updated. Some files have 3 different versions, one for the developer machine, one for staging and another one for the live system. I have to clean up this horrible mess.  How should I start? What is an intelligent strategy to deal with duplicated values in different files, multiple copies of the same file and multiple versions for different build environments? How can I store everything in one place without creating a "dependency magnet"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your prayers is ConfigGen. Check it out on CodePlex: [ConfigGen](http://configgen.codeplex.com/)

It does exactly what you are asking for.

**Update**: 
Look at my examples of usage here: [How to select different app.config for several build configurations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082662/how-to-select-different-app-config-for-several-build-configurations/8082937#8082937)

Answer (score 3):

The clean up is going be painful; you'll have to do a lot of find/replace as you move along. I'd start by leveraging what .NET already offers, which is, put all these settings on `Application.config` (or `Web.config` if an ASP.NET app) and use `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"]` to retrieve the various values. As far as the different environments, there's also support for this out of the box, you can use [appSettings transformations](http://www.tomot.de/en-us/article/5/asp.net/how-to-use-web.config-transforms-to-replace-appsettings-and-connectionstrings)