# app,config not overwritten or changes not picked up with custom app.config files according to Build cofiguration

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, app-config

I am currently creating a solution that must both work with localdb and sqlservercompact 4.0, using EntityFramework Code First. I created therefor extra builconfigurations: LocalDb and SQLCE. Obviously I need different app.config files for these build configurations. [I found this excellent solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082662/how-to-select-different-app-config-for-several-build-configurations)  and used its second option: changing the MSBuild behaviour by using an AfterBuild directive. So I included the XML below in the WPF-application's project file:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Delete Files="$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName).config" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)\Config\App.$(Configuration).config" DestinationFiles="$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName).config" />
  </Target>
```

This works beautifully on my Win8 development laptop at home, but it seems that the directive is ignored on my Win7 desktop at work. I noticed that where my class.dll's have commented out templates to add PreBuild and AfterBuild directives, the WPF-application did not have it. I checked the Build screen to see if the directive was executed and it was. Seemingly the change is not picked up or overwritten once more. What is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind: the solution above was for class libraries, for instance for unit test projects. For desktop applications you do need [Slow Cheetah](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5). Works like a charm.