# How to separate the dev and production *.sln for Visual Studio 2013 projects

Tags: build, visual-studio-2013, continuous-integration, release-management

I've set up my application release process on Jenkins CI. The build command is:

> "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.com" foo.sln /Rebuild "Release" /Out log.txt

The optimization flags (`/LTCG /OPT:REF /OPT:ICF`) are enabled in foo.sln.

When I development on my machine, I would like to disable those flags (so incremental build is available) in order to reduce the build time. My problem is I have to check out foo.sln from version control system (Perforce in my case), disable the flags. However, whenever I need to check in any changes to foo.sln, I have to toggle optimization flags before check-in and after submitted. So my local settings won't get checked in. Is there a way to make this process easier (avoid toggling the local settings)?

I found some similar questions on SO, but those are for Web.config/App.config. Not for foo.sln solution files.

[Using different Web.config in development and production environment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/305447/248430)

[How to select different app.config for several build configurations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8082662/248430)

Answer (score 1):

A VS solution starts with two standard configurations, Debug and Release.  If you need another one and Debug isn't good enough then just add it.

Use Build + Configuration Manager.  Upper left combobox marked "Active Solution Configuration", pick "New".  Give it a distinctive name and copy from Release.  Change the settings you want to be different.  Alter your build command accordingly.