# Visual Studio 2017 Will not copy files to the output directory using CopyToOutputDirectory directive

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I've alwyays used the following method to copy files to my C# project's output directory:

```
<Content Include="x86\SomeFile.dll">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
```

However, this time I'm greeted with the following picture in Visual Studio:
[image: Ignored]

When I hover over the little '-' icon, it shows "Ignored", with no further explanation. I can't remember ever using a different method to have files automatically copied to the output directory, and it's always worked, as you can see from the other two files that have been added and show no errors.
Even when I rename existing files, and I change the CopyToOutputDirectory accordingly, I'm getting the same problem.

Any ideas?

For now I'll resort to creating a post-build event for this file, but that's a pretty ugly work-around.

Comment: `Ignored` here means ignored by source control, maybe because these files are listed in `git.ignore` file for example

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27317837/copy-different-file-to-output-directory-for-release-and-debug Thanks

Comment: Thank you, Pavel Anikhouski! Apparently the x64 and x86 were added to .gitignore. Force-adding them has solved the problem.