# Spring cloud config like solution for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, spring, ms-access, app-config

[Spring Cloud Config](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/) allows to store and provide configuration for applications, multiply deployed to distributed environment. Is there a .NET alternative? So in app.config I can say - get config, or variable, or section from this endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. 
In .Net you have so-called **Build Configurations**. Default for a project is that you have a "debug" and "release" configuration, but you can have many more. Using .Net, you can specify which configuration settings you want for as many build configurations you have, and then load them using something like:

```
var mySettings = ConfigurationManager.GetSetting["mySetting"]; // pseudo, I forgot the exact syntax
```

For cloud-projects, you have a corresponding **CloudConfigurationManager**

This has changed somewhat for UWP projects and .Net Core in which someone else may help me complete the answer. The solution I gave you is valid for most .Net projects though.

[In this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082662/how-to-select-different-app-config-for-several-build-configurations), you get a good tip for something called **SlowCheetah** that helps you with this

Answer (score 0):

This answer is extremely late, but given this question is still online I'd like to point out that for almost as long as this post has been up, Steeltoe has offered a client for Spring Cloud Config Server that plugs into the `IConfiguration` abstractions: https://docs.steeltoe.io/api/v3/configuration/config-server-provider.html

It is also worth noting that (due to lack of demand) the last version of Steeltoe that included support for .NET Framework was 2.5, which hasn't been patched in a while. If you want to use Spring Cloud Config Server in .NET Framework, I'd highly recommend getting in touch with the team [over on github](https://github.com/steeltoeoss/steeltoe).