# Best practices of config value update for build definitions

Tags: c#, .net, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I wanted to ask if somebody have ever made changes to Web API .config file values during the Visual Studio Team Services build (replaced with other values)? Are there any best practices or way how I can achieve it?

Comment: Do you mean as `Web.Debug.config` and `Web.Release.config`? If that's `app.config`, have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082662/how-to-select-different-app-config-for-several-build-configurations?

Comment: I mean Web.config appSettings key values

Comment: Then use `Web.{Build definition}.config`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SlowCheetah](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5) to transform the values in the config file base on the build configuration you specified when queue the build.

You can also use [Replace Tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) task to replace the strings in the file by the variables you created in the build definition.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at `Web.config` [transformations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx). You can have one main `Web.config` file and then define transformations needed based on build definition name in files `Web.{Build definition name}.config`.

Example of such transformation:

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="MyDB" connectionString="ReleaseSQLServer"
            xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Transforms `MyDB` `connectionString` attribute from any previous value to `ReleaseSQLServer`.

Comment: How can i pass (if it's possible) VSO defined variables to these configs?

Comment: What do you mean by "VSO defined variables"?

Comment: We can define multiple varibles under realese or build definition

Comment: You cannot have variables in definitions like those. These must be hardcoded values. If you want to be more flexible you will need to use some extension.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from using Config Transformations, there are a number of extensions that can make your life easier in this respect:

- [Config transformation extensions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=transform&target=VSTS&sortBy=Relevance)
- [Token replace extensions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=replace&target=VSTS&sortBy=Relevance)
- [And there's one that uses naming by convention to make your life easier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pascalnaber.PascalNaber-Xpirit-WebAppConfiguration)