# Replace endpoint values in config file during build based on specific environment?

Tags: angular, npm, webpack, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm working on Angular 2/4/5 application for a while now (that's why 2/4/5), using `webpack` to bundle everything, etc. The application itself communicates with a backend API written in C#. We're at a stage right now that we need to support 4 different environments which results in 4 different endpoints for the mentioned backend API, so I started exploring options how I can replace the values for the endpoints during `npm run build:environment` in combination with VSTS build definition that should also do the transformation when running a specific script.

This is how the config file looks like:

```
const AppConfig = {     
    hubName: "eventhub",
    baseApiUrl: "https://endpoint.com/api/",
    baseUrl: "https://endpoint.com/"
};
```

I started with `webpack.prod.js` and `webpack.dev.js` and I have two scripts configured: `build:prod` and `build:dev`. Both of those `webpack` files are setting the value for `process.env.ENV` to `production` and `development` respectively. Using that info, I tried reading the value for `process.env.ENV` in `config.ts` file and just doing `switch/case` and setting the value for `baseApiUrl` and `baseUrl` based on the value, however that didn't work, it kept defaulting back to `development` all the time, so I abandoned that approach and started exploring other options, like using `normalModuleReplacementPlugin` for `webpack`, but with little success.

Are there any better ways of replacing specific properties of a config file during execution of the build task?

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38116352/best-practices-of-config-value-update-for-build-definitions?rq=1) SO post will help you with what you need and set you on the right track

Comment: Thanks! This post provided valuable insights for me, however the proposed answer is actually a perfect solutions for me.

Comment: I am wondering, how is this not getting much more attention and how is this not solved yet by angular team?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do even better with webpack [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) since it would replace variables right inside your typescript code with the value you would specify in your webpack config files.

PS: but in my case I don't specify exact values - instead I read values from process.env inside webpack config so I do need only one config:

```ts
plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.ENV)
    })
]
```