# How Can I access to the AppSetting inside a DbMigration?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I need access on the Up() function to the appsetting from other project.

My problem is that I can not load a constructor in the migration.

```
public partial class MyMigration : DbMigration {    
    public override void Up() {
         // Here I need access to my appSettings    
    } 
}
```

Comment: May I ask why you need these app settings? IMO you shouldn't want to introduce that kind of dependency into your migrations code.

Comment: Because I need search a substring that constains the appSettings of my web.

Comment: Well, that's not much of an answer.

Comment: It's a bussiness requirement, sorry. I can not describe more of the reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Be carrefull with that, not a best practice. You also could have to rollback if you want your init app config back. This link could help you too: [How to select different app.config for several build configurations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082662/how-to-select-different-app-config-for-several-build-configurations)

```
var path = @"C:\somepath\Configuration\App.config";
string confFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
var pathFilterRoot = Path.GetPathRoot(confFolder);
string configFileToOPen = Path.GetFileName(pathFilterRoot);

ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMapConfig = new ExeConfigurationFileMap  {
    ExeConfigFilename = Path.Combine(Path.GetFullPath(pathFilterRoot + "\\" + configFileToOPen))
};

System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMapConfig, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```