# Azure Worker Role Config File Transformations

Tags: azure, app-config, azure-worker-roles

I've setup a new worker role and setup a couple of new config transforms for it via SlowCheetah. When I build the project with one of the new configs selected, I do in fact see that configs folder get created underneath the \bin folder as you would expect (for ex. \bin\Production).

When I package a cloud service for deployment using one of the new configs, my web projects get their configs transformed appropriately but my worker role (which is just a library) does not even though I see underneath the \bin folder an updated \bin\production.

It would appear the azure packaging tooling is ignoring the config set for the worker role library. How can I get it to pick the config file from the appropriate the configuration?

Comment: cspack (azure packaging tools) does not depend on application configuration (app.config) instead it use service definition, as described here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg432988.aspx. If you can provide more info on what app config settings you would want to include in build configuration and how they are defined, I can help. Also how do u build your package, command line or VS UI.

Comment: Via VS UI. I'm attempting to port an application to Azure and don't want to have to re-write large chunks of it to ignore the app.config. Things like system.net.mail configurations that I normally transform via config transforms.

Comment: I have used SlowCheetah in the past and found that it only works for developers who have it installed - it does NOT work for developers who do not have it installed. In other words, the changes it makes to your `.csproj` are NOT enough to make it "just work" for everybody else - *something additional* is required. I don't know what that *something additional* is, though. :-(

Comment: This is all irrelevant now. SlowCheetah now supports Azure Worker Role config transforms. Hooray!

Comment: @JamesAlexander SlowCheetah does not transform app.Production.config when create package is azure. How did you made it?

Comment: @fiberOptics they added support for it over a year ago per my last comment. I use it often

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can do this - and it is even very easy once you know how.
App.config is not transformed *by design* but fortunately the Azure Team made the build/deploy process very extensible exactly for these kinds of scenarios. What you need to do is reasonably well documented, though in a very roundabout way and most articles assume you are already familiar with MSBuild scripts and the like.

Below you will find the lines you need to put into your project that will make this Just Work. That should take no more than five minutes.  Please note that this is not a hack - the whole Azure deploy process is designed to support this kind of thing.

If you want to know more, there are some links to related articles at the bottom.

### Some conceptual points

1. The recommended way to achieve this kind of thing in Azure is to *not* use Web.config and App.config but instead use the CloudConfigurationManager and use Role Settings. However, sometimes that just isn't the right answer, usually because of built-in or 3rd party components that require *.config settings (smtp, wcf, elmah etc).
2. Web Config transformations is designed for transforming only the web.config. This means that app.config is not transformed *by design*.
3. Web Config transformations is designed to only kick in when *publishing* so when you run locally, even in the Cloud Emulator, your Web.config won't be transformed.

The way we can solve this is by hooking into the build process for the Cloud project. When you deploy the project to Azure, the Cloud project will be built using a build process you can hook into. In short, the cloud project builds the web and worker roles and puts them under the Obj folder under your cloud project. It then runs a process that essentially zips all that up and finally put the result into the Bin folder. From there, the "zip" file and a configuration file is uploaded to Azure.

### The solution

Is to manually edit your Cloud.csproj file (if you do it from within Visual Studio you need to unload the project first).
Then add this right above the closing `</project>` tag:

```
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets" />
    <PropertyGroup>
      <WorkerRoleDir>$(IntermediateOutputPath)WorkerRole1\</WorkerRoleDir>
      <AppConfigOriginal>$(WorkerRoleDir)WorkerRole1.dll.config</AppConfigOriginal>
      <AppConfigTransformer>$(SolutionDir)WorkerRole1\App.$(Configuration).config</AppConfigTransformer>
      <AppConfigAfterTransformed>$(WorkerRoleDir)AfterTransformed.config</AppConfigAfterTransformed>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Target Name="TransformAppConfig" AfterTargets="AfterPackageComputeService">
      <Message Text="Transforming $(AppConfigOriginal) via $(AppConfigTransformer) to $(AppConfigAfterTransformed)" />
      <TransformXml Source="$(AppConfigOriginal)" Transform="$(AppConfigTransformer)" Destination="$(AppConfigAfterTransformed)" />
      <Copy SourceFiles="$(AppConfigOriginal)" DestinationFiles="$(WorkerRoleDir)App.Config.Original" />
      <Copy SourceFiles="$(AppConfigAfterTransformed)" DestinationFiles="$(AppConfigOriginal)" />
    </Target>
```

### Notes

- There are a couple of hard-coded paths in there that you will have to modify. I am sure there is a way to make them soft but that requires more MSBuild skills than I have.
- The transformation will actually *run* when you deploy to your local Cloud Emulator, but it won't be *used*. As such, the result is consistent with the behavior of Web.config which is also not transformed. But, if your transformation was to fail, you will get a build error even when just running in the Emulator.
- See also [This other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6187118/app-config-transformations)
- [An in-depth exploration](http://blog.slalom.com/2011/08/19/building-and-deploying-windows-azure-projects-using-msbuild-and-tfs-2010/)
- [Tom Hollanders highly linked article on deploying directly from MSBuild](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2011/12/06/automated-build-and-deployment-with-windows-azure-sdk-1-6.aspx)

Comment: Have you got a Production build configuration and are you building using that?

Comment: Actually, I have `Web.Production.config (In MVC), ServiceConfiguration.Production.cscfg (In Cloud Project), app.Production.config (In Worker Role)` but only the `app.Production.config` did not transformed. But `app.Debug.config and app.Release.config` transform properly. So I was thinking to remove all Production config and transfer the values into Debug and Release. Any suggestion?

Comment: I have done removing all `Production` config, and put the proper values on `Debug and Release` config. Everything is working using your config code above. But it would be more better if your code above can transform also custom config like `app.Production.config`

Comment: It can - i use it like that myself. The key is that the project build configuration is not the same as the azure deployment configuration.

Comment: Hmm.. I'm so interested on how you do it. But this is how I usually do it. When I'm creating a package to be deployed, I-right click the Cloud project -> Package -> (a form will show with two combo box, one for `Service Configuration` and the other one is `Build Configuration`). For `SC` I choose `Production` same with `BC`, but `BC` config (`app.Production.config`) in Worker role does not transform. It transform only if I choose `Debug or Release` for `BC`. But no problem transforming Web.Production.config.

Comment: BTW, another problem I found. When I clear the solution, AppConfigOriginal cause an error. It says it cannot find the file. If I remove you custom config and create package for the cloud project, the file came back. Then I'm going to add your config again. Create package again, and transform works (for Debug and Release). But if I clean/rebuild the solution, the error for missing file above is coming back again. I was trying to understand your config code, so that it will not look inside Cloud project obj folder but rather look on WorkerRole project folder for WorkerRole.dll.config.

Comment: Hi, I think I missed some point here `The recommended way to achieve this kind of thing in Azure is to not use Web.config and App.config but instead use the CloudConfigurationManager and use Role Settings.` I did as you say, and everything works fine. Thank you very much. +1

Comment: Glad you made it work by using the other options. I am not sure why the transform was not working. The only thing I can think of is that the solution-level Production BC doesn't use Production BC for all the projects? We use this in production every day so I am confident enough in it :) Good luck!

Answer (score 9):

I find @Frans answer too complicated, and below is the code I found in the [internet](https://github.com/sayedihashimi/slow-cheetah/issues/60#issuecomment-13859725). Given that you already have your app.config transformation set up and working, open your cloud project (.ccproj) in text editor, find this line:

```
<Import Project="$(CloudExtensionsDir)Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets" />
```

and insert the following after it:

```
  <!-- Get worker role transform start -->
  <Target Name="CopyWorkerRoleConfigurations" AfterTargets="CopyWorkerRoleFiles">
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(WorkerTargetDir)\YOUR-PROJECT-NAME.dll.config" DestinationFolder="$(IntermediateOutputPath)YOUR-PROJECT-NAME" OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true" />
  </Target>
  <!-- Get worker role transform end -->
```

and replace YOUR-PROJECT-NAME with your worker project name.

**UPDATE**

I actually found a better way to do this (MSBuild 4+): script above will NOT work if you have more than 1 worker role with app.config transformations in your Azure project. Here is the more generalized way:

```
  <Target Name="CopyWorkerRoleConfigurations" AfterTargets="CopyWorkerRoleFiles">
    <PropertyGroup>
         <RootFolder>$([System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($(MSBuildProjectDirectory)))</RootFolder>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Copy SourceFiles="$(RootFolder)\%(ProjectName)\bin\$(Configuration)\%(EntryPoint).config" DestinationFolder="%(WorkerRoleReferences.OutputDir)" OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true" />
  </Target>
```

Comment: I found I need to tweak this slightly to make it work using TFS Build Services if you have your template set to OutputLocation = SingleFolder. I changed the SourceFiles to <Copy SourceFiles="$(WorkerTargetDir)\%(EntryPoint).config" DestinationFolder="%(WorkerRoleReferences.OutputDir)" OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true" />

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you Cloud Service configurations are set up.  Right-click the cloud project and you should see the configurations you are trying to package.  For example, I rename and use Local, TEST & PROD configurations.  Your Cloud Service project should then contain 3 config files:

- ServiceConfiguration.Local.cscfg
- ServiceConfiguration.PROD.cscfg
- ServiceConfiguration.TEST.cscfg

Right-click the Cloud Service project and select "Package" and select the correct Service & Build configurations for your deployment.

Note: app.configs aren't transformed in the build process unless you add an MS - [See this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6187118/app-config-transformations) for a technique to do a transform in the build process.  Howerver, for cloud deployments, you are better off using ServiceConfiguration.*.cscfg files in combination with `CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("settingsKey")` - CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting was added in SDK 1.7 - if in Role, it gets the value from ServiceConfig else get from web.config/app.config appSettings

Comment: That does not work. The service configurations don't have any effect on the app.config.

Comment: I'd recommend using ServiceConfiguration.*.cscfg file instead of appSettings.  These can be updated in the portal without redeploying your roles.  Answer edited.

Answer (score 0):

There is one trick. Perhaps someone will come in handy. Azure Worker Role builder includes files that marked as "Copy". But app.config will be transform in WorkerRole1.dll.config (or some else), that is not exists in design-time. To cheat VS:

Unload role project .csproj.

Find ItemGroup section with including files in project. I have next few:

```
<None Include="app.config">
  <SubType>Designer</SubType>
</None>
<None Include="app.Debug.config">
  <DependentUpon>app.config</DependentUpon>
</None>
<None Include="app.Release.config">
  <DependentUpon>app.config</DependentUpon>
  <SubType>Designer</SubType>
</None>
```

Then set before or after:

```
<Content Include="bin\$(Configuration)\WorkerRole1.dll.config">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  <Link>WorkerRole1.dll.config</Link>
</Content>
```

This trick says to builder "WorkerRole1.dll.config" is exists as a **link**,  this one will be obtained after build (and transformations) and include in WorkerRole package.

Comment: Slight fix to resolve problems with rebuild (when bin was cleared). Builder tries to copy file that not exists and rebuild goes to fail. To resolve this, insert dummy file with name WorkerRole1.dll.config in project root with Content\Copy Always parameters. Builder will copy dummy first and then will copy successfully. Azure role deployer reads property "Content" of this file and copies new transformed file. This works without any additional copying and slightly clearer.